# Could Not Get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly. React/Taillwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have React and Tailwind CSS installed.
I started by expo. to create a application.

This simple page should allow me to have centered text and a simple button.

My code is below and the error follows. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useTailwind } from "tailwind-rn";
import tailwind from "tailwindcss";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={tailwind("flex-1 justify-center items-center ")}>
            <Text> HELLOOOO</Text>
            <Button title="click me" />
        </View>
    );
}
```

**Error:**

> Could Not Get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to Hermes that come preinstalled in React Native. If you disable it, most likely it would go away. [I have attached a reference of how to disable it inside you android/app/build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94q06.png)